# I have error flutter null safety migration

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm migration the flutter firebase code that I wrote in sdk 2.7 to the null safety version, and there's a problem.
There is a problem with snapshot.data() among the firebase user model codes.

```
  UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, this.userKey, {this.reference})
      : profileImg = map[KEY_PROFILEIMG],
        username = map[KEY_USERNAME],
        email = map[KEY_EMAIL],
        likedPosts = map[KEY_LIKEDPOSTS],
        followers = map[KEY_FOLLOWERS],
        followings = map[KEY_FOLLOWINGS],
        myPosts = map[KEY_MYPOSTS];

  UserModel.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data(), snapshot.id, //snapshot.data() error
            reference: snapshot.reference);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbstS.png)

error of snapshot.data()

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

May I know about this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a deeper look at null-safty first, its confusing at first, but soon you'll understand it easily.
However, long story short, **null-safty means variables can't be null unless you specify that with '?' after the type**.
In your code, you specified the first argument of `fromMap`, which is map, that it can't be null, because you didn't add '?', and `snapshot.data()` may return null.

To fix it you either:

- Make map nullable using ? to be like -> `Map<String, dynamic>? map` which  is not good, because it fromMap function.
- Check the value of `snapshot.data()` if its null:

  - Don't call `fromMap`.
  - Or pass an alternative value like empty object `{}`